# Light emission from atoms in an expanding Universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, particle-physics, visible-light

Our universe is expanding so every body is in acceleration. Now, all of atom of universe in acceleration. Why accelerating atoms don't produce photons?

Comment: According to Maxwell, an accelerating charge produced EM waves which is photons, but an atom is not charged $q_p=+e , q_e=-e \to q_{\text{atom}}=0$

Comment: @Electroelf That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Atoms have electrons and when accelerated will emit photons.

Comment: Well yes, but Maxwell was talking about a charge not an atom, an electron or proton for example .

Comment: @Electroelf you were the one that said atom in your question. Protons as well as neutrons and electrons emit photons

Comment: The matter in the universe is not accelerating, the space itself is expanding. And according to the Bohr model, the electrons move in stationary orbits, in which they cannot emit radiation by acceleration.

Comment: My question ? I correct his assumption atom is not charged, according to the electromagnetic theory only charged particles emit EM waves, which is in QM photons !

Answer (score 1):

> Our universe is expanding so every body is in acceleration.Now, all of atom of universe in acceleration

In just an expanding universe, the space expansion is steady, no acceleration.

But we have observed an [accelerated expansion of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerating_expansion_of_the_universe) , and the question could apply to it, except for the following facts.

The macroscopic forces holding matter together as we observe now in our present universe, are orders of magnitude stronger than a possible force that the accelerated expansion, observed using cosmological models of the universe, can impose. Thus galaxies and planets and the matter they contain as atoms and molecules are not affected by the expansion in their binding by the various potentials , whether expressed in the classical framework  or the quantum framework.

> Why accelerating atoms don't produce photons?

As discussed in the comments to your question, bound matter is generally not charged, and only charged particles emit electromagnetic radiation when accelerated.

[Hubbles law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) shows that the universe is expanding by studying the redshift of galaxies. Accelerated expansion is a small change on the expansion. Maybe  if one had a free charged body, for example a charged black hole not bound in  a galaxy, one could calculate what amount of  its radiation ( normaly due to [Hawking radiation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) could come from the accelerating expansion, but it would certainly not be detectable, as we have not been able to measure Hawking radiation yet. Charged black holes behavior is a matter of [theoretical research](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1693465).

Comment: Most baryonic matter in the universe is ionised.

Comment: @RobJeffries sure, but the question is not about ionized atoms, and the fact that most matter is bound in at least a gravitational field holds, so it  is not "feeling" expansion let alone acceleration of expansion.

Comment: Not necessarily, if matter has charged particles like in atoms(protons and electrons) it will emit black body radiation. However it should be noted that nothing is accelerating. Space itself is accelerating faster than the speed of light. Einstein's theory of relativity said no matter or light can go faster than the speed of light but said no limit on the speed of space itself. The actual matter is not accelerating or moving at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial assumption is wrong. The universe expanding means that distances between galaxies are increasing. It does not imply that anything is accelerating. Whether or not the rate of expansion is accelerating, galaxies follow geodesics and are not subject to (proper) acceleration.

[image: expanding universe]